# Is it possible to use adjacent selector with less

Tags: css, less

I wonder if I can use the adjacent selector in LESS. Here's a piece of code :

HTML

```
<input id="my-input" type="text" class="my-class"/>
<label for="my-input" />
```

LESS

```
.my-class {
    display: none;

    &+label {
        color: red;
    }
}
```

I'm getting an error when compiling this LESS code. It says `Unrecognized Input at line XX (&+label)`

Any ideas ?

### EDIT

Actually I get this error when I add one more nested rule like this :

```
.my-class {
    display: none;

    &+label {
        color: red;

        &:hover {
            background-color: grey;
            color: blue;
        }
    }
}
```

I don't if this is a bug or not.

Comment: have you tried without `&` ?

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan Yes I tried but it doesn't work.

Comment: how strange, in http://lesstester.com/ both the versions (with and without `&`) work

Comment: Well, I tried this code on your web site, and it worked. But my full code doesn't work. I'm investigating.